# How to get view any file functionality as we get in gmail using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, browser, view

I have to create code to view any type of file in the browser as we are able to view in gmail.

Even though the user does not have the required software installed he should be able to view it.

The file should not be open in separate window.

The file should be opened in the browser itself

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "any file", I'm pretty sure gmail won't know what to do with an AutoCAD file for example.  Are you just limiting it to office/pdf type documents?

Comment: If you want to view "any file" you'll need code on your server to read any formats you're interested in & convert them to html.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to process it on the server-side into some data structure that can be rendered in html/css/js on the client